# Funcionamiento de los dispatch en Objetive C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Me gustaría saber para que sirven exactamente y como se suelen utilizar los dispatch, como por ejemplo este:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue( ), ^{

  //tu código

} );
```

Muchas gracias!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

este codigo en particular lo que hace es ejecutar la piesa de codigo  entr llaves en el hilo principal o Main thread en Inglés, ten encuenta que en iOS se recomienda hacer todas las operaciones relativas a la UI en la main thread, asi que cuando haces un request, o consultas una operacion que puede demorar un tiempo considerable lo haces en una hilo secundario, pero al actualizar debes hacerlo asi usando este metodo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ok no hay de que